In a custom Ukelele layout on Mac, how do I make ctrl+n and ctrl+p navigation work in the address bar of a browser (e.g. Chrome, Firefox)?
Does anyone know how to make ctrl+n and ctrl+p navigate up and down in a browser's address bar on a custom Ukelele layout on a Mac like the built-in layouts do?
A lesser-known, perhaps undocumented, feature of various browsers is that you can navigate down with ctrl+p and up with ctrl+n in the address bar on a Mac, like with the down/up arrows and tab/shift-tab. I often use the ctrl shortcuts since they are the same in Vim. This works with any built-in keyboard layout on Mac, e.g., "US" or "Swedish".
I created this custom layout in Ukelele based on US QWERTY (I removed a layer to meet the character limit):
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE keyboard SYSTEM "file://localhost/System/Library/DTDs/KeyboardLayout.dtd">
<!--Created by Ukelele version 396 on 2024-10-10 at 11:25 (EEST)-->
<!--Last edited by Ukelele version 396 on 2024-10-12 at 17:44 (EEST)-->
<keyboard group="126" id="-8526" name="US-SV" maxout="1">
    <layouts>
        <layout first="0" last="17" mapSet="ANSI" modifiers="Modifiers"/>
        <layout first="18" last="18" mapSet="JIS" modifiers="Modifiers"/>
        <layout first="21" last="23" mapSet="JIS" modifiers="Modifiers"/>
        <layout first="30" last="30" mapSet="JIS" modifiers="Modifiers"/>
        <layout first="33" last="33" mapSet="JIS" modifiers="Modifiers"/>
        <layout first="36" last="36" mapSet="JIS" modifiers="Modifiers"/>
        <layout first="194" last="194" mapSet="JIS" modifiers="Modifiers"/>
        <layout first="197" last="197" mapSet="JIS" modifiers="Modifiers"/>
        <layout first="200" last="201" mapSet="JIS" modifiers="Modifiers"/>
        <layout first="206" last="207" mapSet="JIS" modifiers="Modifiers"/>
    </layouts>
    <modifierMap id="Modifiers" defaultIndex="0">
        <keyMapSelect mapIndex="0">
            <modifier keys=""/>
        </keyMapSelect>
        <keyMapSelect mapIndex="1">
            <modifier keys="anyShift"/>
        </keyMapSelect>
        <keyMapSelect mapIndex="2">
            <modifier keys="anyOption"/>
        </keyMapSelect>
        <keyMapSelect mapIndex="3">
            <modifier keys="command"/>
        </keyMapSelect>
        <keyMapSelect mapIndex="4">
            <modifier keys="anyControl"/>
        </keyMapSelect>
    </modifierMap>
    <keyMapSet id="ANSI">
        <keyMap index="0">
            <key code="0" output="a"/>
            <key code="1" output="s"/>
            <key code="2" output="d"/>
            <key code="3" output="f"/>
            <key code="4" output="h"/>
            <key code="5" output="g"/>
            <key code="6" output="z"/>
            <key code="7" output="x"/>
            <key code="8" output="c"/>
            <key code="9" output="v"/>
            <key code="10" output="`"/>
            <key code="11" output="b"/>
            <key code="12" output="q"/>
            <key code="13" output="w"/>
            <key code="14" output="e"/>
            <key code="15" output="r"/>
            <key code="16" output="y"/>
            <key code="17" output="t"/>
            <key code="18" output="1"/>
            <key code="19" output="2"/>
            <key code="20" output="3"/>
            <key code="21" output="4"/>
            <key code="22" output="6"/>
            <key code="23" output="5"/>
            <key code="24" output="="/>
            <key code="25" output="9"/>
            <key code="26" output="7"/>
            <key code="27" output="-"/>
            <key code="28" output="8"/>
            <key code="29" output="0"/>
            <key code="30" output="]"/>
            <key code="31" output="o"/>
            <key code="32" output="u"/>
            <key code="33" output="["/>
            <key code="34" output="i"/>
            <key code="35" output="p"/>
            <key code="36" output="&#x000D;"/>
            <key code="37" output="l"/>
            <key code="38" output="j"/>
            <key code="39" output="&#x0027;"/>
            <key code="40" output="k"/>
            <key code="41" output=";"/>
            <key code="42" output="\"/>
            <key code="43" output=","/>
            <key code="44" output="/"/>
            <key code="45" output="n"/>
            <key code="46" output="m"/>
            <key code="47" output="."/>
            <key code="48" output="&#x0009;"/>
            <key code="49" output=" "/>
            <key code="50" output="`"/>
            <key code="51" output="&#x0008;"/>
            <key code="53" output="&#x001B;"/>
            <key code="64" output="&#x0010;"/>
            <key code="65" output=""/>
            <key code="66" output="&#x001D;"/>
            <key code="67" output="*"/>
            <key code="69" output="+"/>
            <key code="70" output="&#x001C;"/>
            <key code="71" output="&#x001B;"/>
            <key code="72" output="&#x001F;"/>
            <key code="75" output="/"/>
            <key code="76" output="&#x0003;"/>
            <key code="77" output="&#x001E;"/>
            <key code="78" output="-"/>
            <key code="79" output="&#x0010;"/>
            <key code="80" output="&#x0010;"/>
            <key code="81" output="="/>
            <key code="82" output="0"/>
            <key code="83" output="1"/>
            <key code="84" output="2"/>
            <key code="85" output="3"/>
            <key code="86" output="4"/>
            <key code="87" output="5"/>
            <key code="88" output="6"/>
            <key code="89" output="7"/>
            <key code="91" output="8"/>
            <key code="92" output="9"/>
            <key code="96" output="&#x0010;"/>
            <key code="97" output="&#x0010;"/>
            <key code="98" output="&#x0010;"/>
            <key code="99" output="&#x0010;"/>
            <key code="100" output="&#x0010;"/>
            <key code="101" output="&#x0010;"/>
            <key code="103" output="&#x0010;"/>
            <key code="105" output="&#x0010;"/>
            <key code="106" output="&#x0010;"/>
            <key code="107" output="&#x0010;"/>
            <key code="109" output="&#x0010;"/>
            <key code="111" output="&#x0010;"/>
            <key code="113" output="&#x0010;"/>
            <key code="114" output="&#x0005;"/>
            <key code="115" output="&#x0001;"/>
            <key code="116" output="&#x000B;"/>
            <key code="117" output="&#x007F;"/>
            <key code="118" output="&#x0010;"/>
            <key code="119" output="&#x0004;"/>
            <key code="120" output="&#x0010;"/>
            <key code="121" output="&#x000C;"/>
            <key code="122" output="&#x0010;"/>
            <key code="123" output="&#x001C;"/>
            <key code="124" output="&#x001D;"/>
            <key code="125" output="&#x001F;"/>
            <key code="126" output="&#x001E;"/>
        </keyMap>
        <keyMap index="1">
            <key code="0" output="A"/>
            <key code="1" output="S"/>
            <key code="2" output="D"/>
            <key code="3" output="F"/>
            <key code="4" output="H"/>
            <key code="5" output="G"/>
            <key code="6" output="Z"/>
            <key code="7" output="X"/>
            <key code="8" output="C"/>
            <key code="9" output="V"/>
            <key code="10" output=""/>
            <key code="11" output="B"/>
            <key code="12" output="Q"/>
            <key code="13" output="W"/>
            <key code="14" output="E"/>
            <key code="15" output="R"/>
            <key code="16" output="Y"/>
            <key code="17" output="T"/>
            <key code="18" output="!"/>
            <key code="19" output="@"/>
            <key code="20" output="#"/>
            <key code="21" output="$"/>
            <key code="22" output="^"/>
            <key code="23" output="%"/>
            <key code="24" output="+"/>
            <key code="25" output="("/>
            <key code="26" output="&#x0026;"/>
            <key code="27" output="_"/>
            <key code="28" output="*"/>
            <key code="29" output=")"/>
            <key code="30" output="}"/>
            <key code="31" output="O"/>
            <key code="32" output="U"/>
            <key code="33" output="{"/>
            <key code="34" output="I"/>
            <key code="35" output="P"/>
            <key code="36" output="&#x000D;"/>
            <key code="37" output="L"/>
            <key code="38" output="J"/>
            <key code="39" output="&#x0022;"/>
            <key code="40" output="K"/>
            <key code="41" output=":"/>
            <key code="42" output="|"/>
            <key code="43" output="&#x003C;"/>
            <key code="44" output="?"/>
            <key code="45" output="N"/>
            <key code="46" output="M"/>
            <key code="47" output="&#x003E;"/>
            <key code="48" output="&#x0009;"/>
            <key code="49" output=" "/>
            <key code="50" output="~"/>
            <key code="51" output="&#x0008;"/>
            <key code="53" output="&#x001B;"/>
            <key code="64" output="&#x0010;"/>
            <key code="65" output=""/>
            <key code="66" output="&#x001D;"/>
            <key code="67" output="*"/>
            <key code="69" output="+"/>
            <key code="70" output="&#x001C;"/>
            <key code="71" output="&#x001B;"/>
            <key code="72" output="&#x001F;"/>
            <key code="75" output="/"/>
            <key code="76" output="&#x0003;"/>
            <key code="77" output="&#x001E;"/>
            <key code="78" output="-"/>
            <key code="79" output="&#x0010;"/>
            <key code="80" output="&#x0010;"/>
            <key code="81" output="="/>
            <key code="82" output="0"/>
            <key code="83" output="1"/>
            <key code="84" output="2"/>
            <key code="85" output="3"/>
            <key code="86" output="4"/>
            <key code="87" output="5"/>
            <key code="88" output="6"/>
            <key code="89" output="7"/>
            <key code="91" output="8"/>
            <key code="92" output="9"/>
            <key code="96" output="&#x0010;"/>
            <key code="97" output="&#x0010;"/>
            <key code="98" output="&#x0010;"/>
            <key code="99" output="&#x0010;"/>
            <key code="100" output="&#x0010;"/>
            <key code="101" output="&#x0010;"/>
            <key code="103" output="&#x0010;"/>
            <key code="105" output="&#x0010;"/>
            <key code="106" output="&#x0010;"/>
            <key code="107" output="&#x0010;"/>
            <key code="109" output="&#x0010;"/>
            <key code="111" output="&#x0010;"/>
            <key code="113" output="&#x0010;"/>
            <key code="114" output="&#x0005;"/>
            <key code="115" output="&#x0001;"/>
            <key code="116" output="&#x000B;"/>
            <key code="117" output="&#x007F;"/>
            <key code="118" output="&#x0010;"/>
            <key code="119" output="&#x0004;"/>
            <key code="120" output="&#x0010;"/>
            <key code="121" output="&#x000C;"/>
            <key code="122" output="&#x0010;"/>
            <key code="123" output="&#x001C;"/>
            <key code="124" output="&#x001D;"/>
            <key code="125" output="&#x001F;"/>
            <key code="126" output="&#x001E;"/>
        </keyMap>
        <keyMap index="2">
            <key code="0" output="ä"/>
            <key code="1" output="s"/>
            <key code="2" output=""/>
            <key code="3" output=""/>
            <key code="4" output=""/>
            <key code="5" output=""/>
            <key code="6" output=""/>
            <key code="7" output=""/>
            <key code="8" output=""/>
            <key code="9" output=""/>
            <key code="10" output=""/>
            <key code="11" output=""/>
            <key code="12" output=""/>
            <key code="13" output="å"/>
            <key code="14" output="€"/>
            <key code="15" output=""/>
            <key code="16" output=""/>
            <key code="17" output=""/>
            <key code="18" output=""/>
            <key code="19" output=""/>
            <key code="20" output=""/>
            <key code="21" output=""/>
            <key code="22" output=""/>
            <key code="23" output=""/>
            <key code="24" output=""/>
            <key code="25" output=""/>
            <key code="26" output=""/>
            <key code="27" output="–"/>
            <key code="28" output=""/>
            <key code="29" output=""/>
            <key code="30" output=""/>
            <key code="31" output="ö"/>
            <key code="32" output=""/>
            <key code="33" output=""/>
            <key code="34" output="i"/>
            <key code="35" output="å"/>
            <key code="36" output="&#x000D;"/>
            <key code="37" output=""/>
            <key code="38" output=""/>
            <key code="39" output=""/>
            <key code="40" output=""/>
            <key code="41" output=""/>
            <key code="42" output=""/>
            <key code="43" output=""/>
            <key code="44" output=""/>
            <key code="45" output=""/>
            <key code="46" output=""/>
            <key code="47" output=""/>
            <key code="48" output="&#x0009;"/>
            <key code="49" output=""/>
            <key code="50" output=""/>
            <key code="51" output="&#x0008;"/>
            <key code="53" output="&#x001B;"/>
            <key code="64" output="&#x0010;"/>
            <key code="65" output=""/>
            <key code="66" output="&#x001D;"/>
            <key code="67" output=""/>
            <key code="69" output=""/>
            <key code="70" output="&#x001C;"/>
            <key code="71" output="&#x001B;"/>
            <key code="72" output="&#x001F;"/>
            <key code="75" output=""/>
            <key code="76" output="&#x0003;"/>
            <key code="77" output="&#x001E;"/>
            <key code="78" output=""/>
            <key code="79" output="&#x0010;"/>
            <key code="80" output="&#x0010;"/>
            <key code="81" output=""/>
            <key code="82" output=""/>
            <key code="83" output=""/>
            <key code="84" output=""/>
            <key code="85" output=""/>
            <key code="86" output=""/>
            <key code="87" output=""/>
            <key code="88" output=""/>
            <key code="89" output=""/>
            <key code="91" output=""/>
            <key code="92" output=""/>
            <key code="96" output="&#x0010;"/>
            <key code="97" output="&#x0010;"/>
            <key code="98" output="&#x0010;"/>
            <key code="99" output="&#x0010;"/>
            <key code="100" output="&#x0010;"/>
            <key code="101" output="&#x0010;"/>
            <key code="103" output="&#x0010;"/>
            <key code="105" output="&#x0010;"/>
            <key code="106" output="&#x0010;"/>
            <key code="107" output="&#x0010;"/>
            <key code="109" output="&#x0010;"/>
            <key code="111" output="&#x0010;"/>
            <key code="113" output="&#x0010;"/>
            <key code="114" output="&#x0005;"/>
            <key code="115" output="&#x0001;"/>
            <key code="116" output="&#x000B;"/>
            <key code="117" output="&#x007F;"/>
            <key code="118" output="&#x0010;"/>
            <key code="119" output="&#x0004;"/>
            <key code="120" output="&#x0010;"/>
            <key code="121" output="&#x000C;"/>
            <key code="122" output="&#x0010;"/>
            <key code="123" output="&#x001C;"/>
            <key code="124" output="&#x001D;"/>
            <key code="125" output="&#x001F;"/>
            <key code="126" output="&#x001E;"/>
        </keyMap>
        <keyMap index="3">
            <key code="0" output="a"/>
            <key code="1" output="s"/>
            <key code="2" output="d"/>
            <key code="3" output="f"/>
            <key code="4" output="h"/>
            <key code="5" output="g"/>
            <key code="6" output="z"/>
            <key code="7" output="x"/>
            <key code="8" output="c"/>
            <key code="9" output="v"/>
            <key code="10" output=""/>
            <key code="11" output="b"/>
            <key code="12" output="q"/>
            <key code="13" output="w"/>
            <key code="14" output="e"/>
            <key code="15" output="r"/>
            <key code="16" output="y"/>
            <key code="17" output="t"/>
            <key code="18" output="1"/>
            <key code="19" output="2"/>
            <key code="20" output="3"/>
            <key code="21" output="4"/>
            <key code="22" output="6"/>
            <key code="23" output="5"/>
            <key code="24" output="="/>
            <key code="25" output="9"/>
            <key code="26" output="7"/>
            <key code="27" output="-"/>
            <key code="28" output="8"/>
            <key code="29" output="0"/>
            <key code="30" output="]"/>
            <key code="31" output="o"/>
            <key code="32" output="u"/>
            <key code="33" output="["/>
            <key code="34" output="i"/>
            <key code="35" output="p"/>
            <key code="36" output="&#x000D;"/>
            <key code="37" output="l"/>
            <key code="38" output="j"/>
            <key code="39" output="&#x0027;"/>
            <key code="40" output="k"/>
            <key code="41" output=";"/>
            <key code="42" output="\"/>
            <key code="43" output=","/>
            <key code="44" output="/"/>
            <key code="45" output="n"/>
            <key code="46" output="m"/>
            <key code="47" output="."/>
            <key code="48" output="&#x0009;"/>
            <key code="49" output=" "/>
            <key code="50" output="`"/>
            <key code="51" output="&#x0008;"/>
            <key code="53" output="&#x001B;"/>
            <key code="64" output="&#x0010;"/>
            <key code="65" output=""/>
            <key code="66" output="&#x001D;"/>
            <key code="67" output="*"/>
            <key code="69" output="+"/>
            <key code="70" output="&#x001C;"/>
            <key code="71" output="&#x001B;"/>
            <key code="72" output="&#x001F;"/>
            <key code="75" output="/"/>
            <key code="76" output="&#x0003;"/>
            <key code="77" output="&#x001E;"/>
            <key code="78" output="-"/>
            <key code="79" output="&#x0010;"/>
            <key code="80" output="&#x0010;"/>
            <key code="81" output="="/>
            <key code="82" output="0"/>
            <key code="83" output="1"/>
            <key code="84" output="2"/>
            <key code="85" output="3"/>
            <key code="86" output="4"/>
            <key code="87" output="5"/>
            <key code="88" output="6"/>
            <key code="89" output="7"/>
            <key code="91" output="8"/>
            <key code="92" output="9"/>
            <key code="96" output="&#x0010;"/>
            <key code="97" output="&#x0010;"/>
            <key code="98" output="&#x0010;"/>
            <key code="99" output="&#x0010;"/>
            <key code="100" output="&#x0010;"/>
            <key code="101" output="&#x0010;"/>
            <key code="103" output="&#x0010;"/>
            <key code="105" output="&#x0010;"/>
            <key code="106" output="&#x0010;"/>
            <key code="107" output="&#x0010;"/>
            <key code="109" output="&#x0010;"/>
            <key code="111" output="&#x0010;"/>
            <key code="113" output="&#x0010;"/>
            <key code="114" output="&#x0005;"/>
            <key code="115" output="&#x0001;"/>
            <key code="116" output="&#x000B;"/>
            <key code="117" output="&#x007F;"/>
            <key code="118" output="&#x0010;"/>
            <key code="119" output="&#x0004;"/>
            <key code="120" output="&#x0010;"/>
            <key code="121" output="&#x000C;"/>
            <key code="122" output="&#x0010;"/>
            <key code="123" output="&#x001C;"/>
            <key code="124" output="&#x001D;"/>
            <key code="125" output="&#x001F;"/>
            <key code="126" output="&#x001E;"/>
        </keyMap>
        <keyMap index="4">
            <key code="0" output=""/>
            <key code="1" output=""/>
            <key code="2" output=""/>
            <key code="3" output=""/>
            <key code="4" output=""/>
            <key code="5" output=""/>
            <key code="6" output=""/>
            <key code="7" output=""/>
            <key code="8" output=""/>
            <key code="9" output=""/>
            <key code="10" output=""/>
            <key code="11" output=""/>
            <key code="12" output=""/>
            <key code="13" output=""/>
            <key code="14" output=""/>
            <key code="15" output=""/>
            <key code="16" output=""/>
            <key code="17" output=""/>
            <key code="18" output=""/>
            <key code="19" output=""/>
            <key code="20" output=""/>
            <key code="21" output=""/>
            <key code="22" output=""/>
            <key code="23" output=""/>
            <key code="24" output=""/>
            <key code="25" output=""/>
            <key code="26" output=""/>
            <key code="27" output=""/>
            <key code="28" output=""/>
            <key code="29" output=""/>
            <key code="30" output=""/>
            <key code="31" output=""/>
            <key code="32" output=""/>
            <key code="33" output=""/>
            <key code="34" output=""/>
            <key code="35" output=""/>
            <key code="36" output="&#x000D;"/>
            <key code="37" output=""/>
            <key code="38" output=""/>
            <key code="39" output=""/>
            <key code="40" output=""/>
            <key code="41" output=""/>
            <key code="42" output=""/>
            <key code="43" output=""/>
            <key code="44" output=""/>
            <key code="45" output=""/>
            <key code="46" output=""/>
            <key code="47" output=""/>
            <key code="48" output="&#x0009;"/>
            <key code="49" output=""/>
            <key code="50" output=""/>
            <key code="51" output="&#x0008;"/>
            <key code="53" output="&#x001B;"/>
            <key code="55" output=""/>
            <key code="58" output=""/>
            <key code="64" output="&#x0010;"/>
            <key code="65" output=""/>
            <key code="66" output="&#x001D;"/>
            <key code="67" output=""/>
            <key code="69" output=""/>
            <key code="70" output="&#x001C;"/>
            <key code="71" output="&#x001B;"/>
            <key code="72" output="&#x001F;"/>
            <key code="75" output=""/>
            <key code="76" output="&#x0003;"/>
            <key code="77" output="&#x001E;"/>
            <key code="78" output=""/>
            <key code="79" output="&#x0010;"/>
            <key code="80" output="&#x0010;"/>
            <key code="81" output=""/>
            <key code="82" output=""/>
            <key code="83" output=""/>
            <key code="84" output=""/>
            <key code="85" output=""/>
            <key code="86" output=""/>
            <key code="87" output=""/>
            <key code="88" output=""/>
            <key code="89" output=""/>
            <key code="91" output=""/>
            <key code="92" output=""/>
            <key code="96" output="&#x0010;"/>
            <key code="97" output="&#x0010;"/>
            <key code="98" output="&#x0010;"/>
            <key code="99" output="&#x0010;"/>
            <key code="100" output="&#x0010;"/>
            <key code="101" output="&#x0010;"/>
            <key code="103" output="&#x0010;"/>
            <key code="105" output="&#x0010;"/>
            <key code="106" output="&#x0010;"/>
            <key code="107" output="&#x0010;"/>
            <key code="109" output="&#x0010;"/>
            <key code="111" output="&#x0010;"/>
            <key code="113" output="&#x0010;"/>
            <key code="114" output="&#x0005;"/>
            <key code="115" output="&#x0001;"/>
            <key code="116" output="&#x000B;"/>
            <key code="117" output="&#x007F;"/>
            <key code="118" output="&#x0010;"/>
            <key code="119" output="&#x0004;"/>
            <key code="120" output="&#x0010;"/>
            <key code="121" output="&#x000C;"/>
            <key code="122" output="&#x0010;"/>
            <key code="123" output="&#x001C;"/>
            <key code="124" output="&#x001D;"/>
            <key code="125" output="&#x001F;"/>
            <key code="126" output="&#x001E;"/>
        </keyMap>
    </keyMapSet>
    <keyMapSet id="JIS">
        <keyMap index="0" baseMapSet="ANSI" baseIndex="0">
            <key code="512" output=""/>
        </keyMap>
        <keyMap index="1" baseMapSet="ANSI" baseIndex="1">
            <key code="512" output=""/>
        </keyMap>
        <keyMap index="2" baseMapSet="ANSI" baseIndex="2">
            <key code="512" output=""/>
        </keyMap>
        <keyMap index="3" baseMapSet="ANSI" baseIndex="3">
            <key code="512" output=""/>
        </keyMap>
        <keyMap index="4" baseMapSet="ANSI" baseIndex="4">
            <key code="512" output=""/>
        </keyMap>
    </keyMapSet>
</keyboard>

With this layout selected, nothing happens when I press ctrl+n or ctrl+p in Chrome's or Firefox's address bar. Does anyone know why? The keybindings work in Neovim running in kitty, so they are registered correctly.
I've tried mapping ctrl+ n to output "n" directly by changing:
- <key code="45" output=""/>
+ <key code="45" output="n"/>

In <keyMap index="5"> (the ctrl layer), but that doesn't work; only "n" is output then. I've tried the same for ctrl+p with key code 35, resulting in the same problem.

I was able to solve the issue by binding ctrl+n to the down arrow key (&#x001E;) and ctrl+p  to the up arrow key (&#x001F;) like this:
        <keyMap index="4">
...
-            <key code="35" output=""/>
+            <key code="35" output="&#x001E;"/>
...
-            <key code="45" output=""/>
+            <key code="45" output="&#x001F;"/>

I'm unsure if this is how it's bound in, e.g., the default Mac US layout, but it seems to behave exactly the same. I can now move down/up in Chrome's address bar with ctrl+n/p.
